# excel vba: lookup second line of text file and update spreadsheet where cell = value and update other cell in same row with value from text file

Tags: vba, excel, text-files

I have the following code which I am trying to improve.
Firstly it scans a text file and gets the text from the second text line in the file.

I am wanting to change this so it scans just the second line of all .txt files in a folder instead of just one and for each text file check if the second text line = "Approve" or "reject".

Then if it = "Approve", I want my cell in column S to get updated with this value in the row where the first text line in the text file matches a reference number in column C.

An example:

```
Text File - NS123.txt:
NS123
Approve
```

And in my spreadsheet:

Row 1:

```
C            F                R                           S
NS123     Cell Value       Cell Value       Update Cell with Approve/Reject
```

Row 2:

```
C            F                R                           S
NS564     Cell Value       Cell Value       Wont be updated because doesn't match value in column c
```

please can someone show me how I could do this? Thanks

Code:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim fn As Integer
    fn = FreeFile
    Open "Z:\NS\Approval\NS32D1QR.txt" For Input As fn

    Dim wholeFile As String
    wholeFile = Input(LOF(fn), #fn)

    Close #fn

    Dim splitArray
    splitArray = Split(wholeFile, vbCrLf)

    Dim lineNum As Integer
    lineNum = 2


    Dim i As Integer, intValueToFind As Integer
    intValueToFind = NS32D1QR
    For i = 1 To 500    ' Revise the 500 to include all of your values
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = intValueToFind And splitArray(lineNum - 1) = "Approve" Then
    Range("S" & ActiveCell.Row).Value = "Approve"
    End If

    Next i



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the guidelines:

### Scanning all text files in folder:

Use the `Dir` function

```
directory = Dir("*.txt")
Do While directory <> ""
  'Your code
  directory = Dir()
Loop
```

### Checking the second line:

As in my [Tutorial on how to read from files in VBA](http://www.analystcave.com/vba-read-file-vba/):

```
fileNo = FreeFile
Open fileName For Input As #fileNo
Line Input #fileNo, textRow: Line Input #fileNo, textRow 
'Now textRow contains the second row of the file
Close #fileNo
```